# Finding the exact real roots of a system of a sinusoidal and a line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nonlinear-system

Say I have a sinusoidal function $s(x)=\alpha \sin(\beta x - \gamma) + \delta$ and the linear function $f(x)=mx+b$. How can I find $x$ exactly such that $s(x)=f(x)$?

I can't solve it like a normal function because the sine can't be removed.

I know I could use Newton's method or some other iterative method, but is it possible to find an exact answer? I have a feeling it might be done with differential equations, but I don't know how that would be done.

Comment: I don't think one can answer this question without some actual values for the constants. For example, if _m_ = 0 and _b_ is between <alpha> and negative <alpha>, then there are infinite solutions to the system. Can you be more specific on the values you wish to investigate?

Comment: I know that there is exactly one solution for each linear equation in my case, but if you need to know exactly, I'm looking for the intersections of $f(x)=x - 24n$ with $-\frac{37}{20}\sin (\frac{2\pi }{8784}(t-80.5))+6$ and $\frac{37}{20} \sin (\frac{2\pi }{8784}(t-80.5))+18$

Comment: Now I see why you didn't include the details. :) However, unless we know what $n$ is, it would be hard to solve, even if the domain variables were the same. As it is, one cannot assume that $x$ and $t$ describe the same domains. I would use a graphing utility, like Desmos.

Comment: Oh, whoops, x and t are supposed to be the same variable.